# PHP image scaling does not work

Tags: php, image-processing, gd

The script provided below "res.php" is designed to scale images that are then used in HEADER css of the html page. The images are called depending on the "CID" (Club ID). Each Club has there information stored in the database including one called club_header. The club_header is a VARCHAR that stores absolute image location (file-system or web). The "res.php" function is to call image and output it to browser as well as re-size the image to whatever the settings are set for. By default the settings are 960 x 200.

However do to some reason the script is not doing what it has to be and outputs a broken image instead. What may the problem be with the code?

Some server + php info if needed

**Server:** Apache v2.2.21, PHP v5.3.8, SQL v5.5.16, GD v2.0.34

**PHP.ini:** max_execution_time = 300, max_input_time = 60, memory_limit = 208M, post_max_size = 24M

**"res.php" source-code**

```
require("php/db.class.php");

function scaleImageFileToBlob($file) {

    $file = $_GET['cid'];

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM clubs WHERE club_id = '".$_GET['cid']."'");
    $obj = mysql_fetch_array($query);
    $photoObj = $obj['club_header'];

    $source_pic = $photoObj;
    $max_width = 960;
    $max_height = 200;

    list($width, $height, $image_type) = getimagesize($file);

    switch ($image_type)
    {
        case 1: $src = imagecreatefromgif($file); break;
        case 2: $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);  break;
        case 3: $src = imagecreatefrompng($file); break;
        default: return '';  break;
    }

    $x_ratio = $max_width / $width;
    $y_ratio = $max_height / $height;

    if( ($width <= $max_width) && ($height <= $max_height) ){
        $tn_width = $width;
        $tn_height = $height;
        }elseif (($x_ratio * $height) < $max_height){
            $tn_height = ceil($x_ratio * $height);
            $tn_width = $max_width;
        }else{
            $tn_width = ceil($y_ratio * $width);
            $tn_height = $max_height;
    }

    $tmp = imagecreatetruecolor($tn_width,$tn_height);

    /* Check if this image is PNG or GIF, then set if Transparent*/
    if(($image_type == 1) OR ($image_type==3))
    {
        imagealphablending($tmp, false);
        imagesavealpha($tmp,true);
        $transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($tmp, 255, 255, 255, 127);
        imagefilledrectangle($tmp, 0, 0, $tn_width, $tn_height, $transparent);
    }
    imagecopyresampled($tmp,$src,0,0,0,0,$tn_width, $tn_height,$width,$height);

    /*
     * imageXXX() only has two options, save as a file, or send to the browser.
     * It does not provide you the oppurtunity to manipulate the final GIF/JPG/PNG file stream
     * So I start the output buffering, use imageXXX() to output the data stream to the browser, 
     * get the contents of the stream, and use clean to silently discard the buffered contents.
     */
    ob_start();

    switch ($image_type)
    {
        case 1: imagegif($tmp); break;
        case 2: imagejpeg($tmp, NULL, 100);  break; // best quality
        case 3: imagepng($tmp, NULL, 0); break; // no compression
        default: echo ''; break;
    }

    $final_image = ob_get_contents();

    ob_end_clean();

    return $final_image;

}

echo scaleImageFileToBlob($file);
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You're open to SQL injection.

Comment: what dimensions of your picture? (in pixels)

Comment: @arxanas I am aware :), this is running on localhost and its only 1day project so far. So I will deal with security later :) but first have to get everything else working.

Comment: @AlexanderLarikov what do you mean by dimensions? $max_width = 960;
$max_height = 200; are provided in example. But users can upload or submit image as large as 5000x5000 @ 18mb

Comment: It may not help answer your question, but you should stop using `mysql_*` functions. They're being deprecated. Instead use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (supported as of PHP 5.1) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (supported as of PHP 4.1). If you're not sure which one to use, [read this article](http://www.deprecatedphp.com/mysql_/).

Comment: @Matt I been looking into PDO long long time ago. But I can't exactly get a hang of it, know any good resource?

Comment: @Cl' did you click the links in my comment? [Netplusplus](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/?search_index=3) has a pretty good tutorial.

Comment: @Matt Yes, I did. But I still can't get a hang of it. It seems very confusing.

Comment: @Cl' [what about this one](http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/PDO-Prepared-Statement-P550.html)?

Comment: @Matt if image dimensions is too big it'll not fit into available RAM size and you can't resize it using GD, for example for 5000x5000 size you need 5000*5000*8 bytes of memory, use imagick instead

Comment: @AlexanderLarikov why is that comment directed at me?

Comment: @Matt by mistake, should be directed to OP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to send the correct header before the image output, such as

```
header('Content-Type: image/png');

header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

header('Content-Type: image/gif');
```